# Laravel eager load through pivot?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot

I'm trying to eager load some data through an id in a pivot table.

Right now I've just done it manually but wondering if there is a way to do this directly through eloquent with a relation?

```
$ids = $tournament->matches
                  ->pluck('users')
                  ->flatten()
                  ->pluck('pivot')
                  ->pluck('team_id')
                  ->unique();

$teams = \App\Models\Team::whereIn('id', $ids)->get()->keyBy('id');

$tournament->matches->each(function ($match) use ($teams) {
    $match->users->each(function ($user) use ($teams) {
        $user->team = @$teams[$user->pivot->team_id] ?: null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can return the instance of Pivot which extends the Model ultimately. so for ex. in tournament has belongs to many team relation then in tournament model

```
/**
     * @param Model $parent
     * @param array $attributes
     * @param string $table
     * @param bool $exists
     * @return ProjectTeamPivot
     */
    public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
    {
        return new TeamPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
```

and in your team pivot class goes as below

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class TeamPivot extends Pivot
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $casts = [];

   // this is the instance of model itself which represents the intermediate table so you can define any kind of relation as you would define in normal model load it eagerly like
   protected $with = []; // you can always load a model if you fill the relation name in this array
 }
```

for more information head over to here
https://softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/

Comment: Not really getting this at all, trying many thing but nothing is working.

Comment: have you created custom pivot class which represents middle table if so you can query that pivot as you query the normal model? by convention the middle table model is not required but if middle table has information which links to other part of app, we may need the model which represents the middle table and if you have model that represents middle table you would query it as you query any other regular model and that's what making you confused i think.. :)

Comment: Hey, yes, I got it now, works great. Actually very simple, I was overthinking it :-)

Comment: :) great you got it.. :)